# Understanding $a$ and $b$ variables in curve functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, curves

When reading curve formulas I often see letters such as "$a$", "$b$" or "$c$". Im not sure what those mean.

For example the [serpentine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpentine_curve):

$y = \frac{abx}{x^2 + a^2}$

What are $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, they represent any numbers.  So you could take $a=2$ and $b=5$ and the equation would be
$$y=\frac{10x}{x^2+4}\ ,$$
which would be one example of a Serpentine curve.  You could get another example by taking $a=4$ and $b=7$, and so on.

Sometimes you will find that there are restrictions on the values of $a$ and $b$.  For example, in the article you linked, it specifies that $ab>0$.  This is OK in my example because $ab=10$ and $10>0$.  But it would **not** be legitimate to take, for example, $a=3$ and $b=-4$.

Comment: But they dont say what a and b is for? Is it the x and y intercept or something?

Comment: They are just two numbers, take any numbers you like and you will get a Serpentine curve (so long as the product of the numbers is positive).

Comment: In this case you can easily find that the $x$ and $y$ intercepts are both $0$.

Comment: Interesting, so ive drawn my curve and it seems b somehow affects the Y movement: https://jsfiddle.net/m6f8z83x/1/ you can check by changing the b variable

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  You could also consider a simple quadratic $y=ax^2+bx+c$: roughly speaking, $a$ determines the "steepness" of the curve, $b$ determines where it is horizontally, and $c$ determines where it is vertically.